# Internet Explorer minimises on page load

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

We have a couple of sites that use a bespoke CMS (e.g. www.trident-ha.org.uk). In these sites whenever a link is clicked in Internet Explorer the browser will minimise for no particular reason.

This is obviously very frustrating and although we have found a few mentions from other people with this problem nobody seems to have a solution.

Presumably this is something to do with JavaScript but it has us baffled.

Comment: Which versions of IE can you reproduce this on?

Comment: Is it just IE, or all browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only code I know to "minimize" a window would be [`window.blur()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_blur.asp), which actually just removes focus from the window. It works across browsers, so is it possible that there's some IE-only script with this included?

FWIW, I suppose it could also be `window.resizeTo()`, although I suspect you would have set it resizes the window to very small dimensions if that were the case. Really, scan through all the JS files you load looking for any `window.*` functions, as those will be the culprit. There shouldn't (knock on wood) be that many because they're a pretty heavy-handed way to control the user's experience.

Comment: Ok, I don't know whether it was a window.* function but I found some of those in some linked JS files from a colour picker and the issue resolved itself when I removed those links.